# What was the relationship between 诸葛亮和周瑜？

Tags: culture

Why does 周瑜 not help 诸葛亮？

现在在读‘草船借箭’的故事。

诸葛亮和周瑜的关系怎样？

周瑜说：“我得吩咐下属，造箭用的材料，不要给他准备齐全，也不能供应充足，故意给他拖延时间。”

周瑜和诸葛亮不是敌人，战在同样的军队。为什么周瑜不帮诸葛亮？

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about a work of fiction and not Chinese language

Comment: There is currently no stack where this question is on topic. However, your question can be answered easily via the wikipedia articles on 草船借箭 and Zhou Yu.

Comment: 一山二虎 (one mountain two tigers) http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/words/57081/

Comment: “一山不能藏二虎” 我喜欢这句话！ 谢谢！

Comment: I'm not convinced this is off-topic; it appears to be about Chinese literature.  If there's doubt, please raise it on [meta] to gauge the community's opinion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The enemy of my enemy is my friend.**

They may be "friends", but they are still enemies.

They are the minister of two different kingdoms, 蜀 and 吴, they just happen to have a stronger common enemy 魏 so they have to work together to keep each other alive for a while before they get stronger and can defend on their own.

You must have seen that 周瑜 keeps trying to kill 诸葛亮, because he sees 诸葛亮 as a threat in the future when 蜀 and 吴 goes against each other. Obviously when two Kingdoms work together, you can't just kill, that's why he keeps assigning impossible missions to 诸葛亮 so he can use that as an excuse to kill him, but 诸葛亮 never failed and it makes 周瑜 angrier and frustrated. In the end, 周瑜 just ordered his men to kill 诸葛亮 anyways but forseeing that, 诸葛亮 escaped before 周瑜 can catch him.

But on a personal level, 周瑜 just can't stand the fact that there are someone as smart as him and this is what killed him, i think this is the biggest difference between the two, both are equally smart, but 周瑜 died because of "Sickness"(more like Jealousy), he is young after all, if the two have met at a different time, they could have become great friends.

Much like The Republic of China and The People's Republic of China when they were fighting Japan, they have to put their disagreement aside for a while and fight together. After Japan surrendered, they started fighting against each other again.

Comment: Thanks! When my Chinese gets better, I will read the whole book, maybe then I'll understand more. It helps if I know the background. That is a good comparison, 2 Chinese armies against Japan. 既生瑜何生亮？

Comment: yea, 既生瑜何生亮, pretty much sums up 周瑜's mind before death.